# dig command on linux returning differing results

Tags: nameserver, dig

Running the command `dig` against a particular domain, returns the previous name server details. For example;

```
domain.com.     41068   IN  NS  ns1.nameserver1.com.
```

Now if i run the command `dig +nssearch host.example.com`, followed by the command `dig domain.com', i get a different result.

```
domain.com.     41068   IN  NS  chad.ns.cloudflare.com.
```

- Why is that?
- If i run the dig command i.e.`dig domain.com` several times, it returns the previous name server details. Why is that?

**EDIT**

The name server details had been changed however running the commands in the same window of time produces to different results.

Comment: What changes did you make to the domain recently?

Comment: Can you include the actual domain name?

Comment: @Michael Hampton - The name server had been changed. I would expect it to change however not with every attempt.

Comment: @Motivated Do you have more than one name server?  Are you consistently querying the same exact name server every time?

Comment: @Mike B - No. Yes i am.

Comment: @Håkan Lindqvist - Since the client is operating in stealth mode, i am not in the privilege of publishing the details of the domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## caching

The name server your system is using as a resolver (`/etc/resolv.conf`) is supposed to cache DNS responses.

By using the `+nssearch` switch you bypass the cached records from your resolver (which in Name server jargon is also called a recursive name server ) and directly query the authoritive DNS server(s) and you get records that do not come from cache.
As phrased in the manual:

> **`+[no]recurse`** Toggle the setting of the RD (recursion desired) bit in the query. This bit is set by default, which means dig normally sends
>   recursive queries. Recursion is automatically disabled when the
>   +nssearch or +trace query options are used.
>   **`+[no]nssearch`** When this option is set, dig attempts to find the authoritative name servers for the zone containing the name being
>   looked up and display the SOA record that each name server has for the
>   zone.

An additional complication may be that your resolver is not a single server, but a cluster of recursive DNS servers, each with different cached and/or fresh records.

Comment: I have attempted purging the DNS cache however it still results in the same output. I purged the cache running the command `sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clear restart`followed by `sudo /etc/init.d/networking force-reload`

Comment: Are responses you are getting simply old (and therefore cached) or completely wrong then. - If you manage your own DNS , could you have omitted updating the zone sequence number?

Comment: The zone sequence has been updated. How do i ensure that the DNS cache has been purged? Having used a site such as `http://centralops.net/` indicates that the DNS has definitely changed.